# Merge two data-sets with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working with a database which has two different tables. 1 for default fields, and 1 for user-added fields, and it results in the split up of some the data i need to get into these two tables.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Result:

```
[0] {id: 1, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Smith'}
[1] {id: 2, firstname: 'Michael', lastname:'Jones'}
...
[99] {id: 100, firstname: 'Jerry', lastname:'Brown'}
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Result:

```
[0] {id: 1, favoriteColor: 'Blue'}
[1] {id: 2, favoriteColor: 'Yellow'}
...
[99] {id: 100, favoriteColor: 'Green'}
```

I would like to merge the two data-sets into 1 with all information: id, firstname, lastname, and favoriteColor.

I know how to do it with 2 different queries and running a php/js script on the results. But I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this with just 1 SQL query which is more efficient.

Comment: How do the two tables relate?  and use JOIN syntax to get it.  If a table1 record doesn't have values in table 2 do you still want the table1 record or vice-versa?  If so you need to use an outer join (left, right or full outer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Concept of `join` as below:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.firstname, 
       t1.lastname,
       t2.favoriteColor 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: Alright this is great. Just an additional question. What if table two has more fields that aren't interesting to me. How do I limit the join to only favoriteColor?

Comment: Using `t2.column_name` you can choose any column of table2 as per your requirement and you can add `where t2.column_name = your filter condition`

Comment: @CodeAt30 add `where` clause at the end ex: `where t2.favoriteColor = 'green' `

Comment: If got your answer please accept and upvote @CodeAt30

Comment: table1.id should not equal table2.id.  I think both would be PK's on the respective tables. Now if table2 has in it a foreign key for table1 then that's what one should join on

Answer (score 2):

Use `INNER JOIN` query:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.firstname, table1.lastname, table2.favoriteColor 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: table1.id should not equal table2.id. I think both would be PK's on the respective tables. Now if table2 has in it a foreign key for table1 then that's what one should join on

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use any of the following joins in your case:

```
join

inner join

left join
```

Here it goes a very good explanation: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

Hope this will help you!

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.
Please check [how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Prateek. it was my first answer. I will look at how to write an answer post. Thank you again,